# How to pass a value from for loop to settimeout function

Tags: javascript

Below is my javascript code:

```
function showBranch_init() {
    var id_arr = ["jdc_b1","jdc_b2","jdc_b3","jdc_b4"];
    for(a=0;a<id_arr.length;a++){
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function() {

            showBranch(id_arr[a]); // <-- Right here

        }, 500);
    }
}
```

How can I pass the value of `id_arr[a]` to `showBranch` funcion?

Currently the above code returns `null` for `id_arr[a]`

Comment: my question a is a global variable?

Comment: It's not correct, `a == id_arr.length - 1` for all timeouts.

Comment: But what's the reason for the timeouts anyways? They will be executed all at the same time.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah I just found that out when I used the answer below. I was expecting what will happen is that there will be a delay of 500ms for each execution but it all ran the same time :|

Comment: For that problem, please see [Why does everything display at once, using setTimeout in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18646908/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks the link helped

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by introducing a new scope (by a function call) for each iteration step you can pass the argument like this:

```
function showBranch_init() {
    var id_arr = ["jdc_b1","jdc_b2","jdc_b3","jdc_b4"];
    for(a=0;a<id_arr.length;a++){
        (function(i) {
            timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function() {
                showBranch(id_arr[i]); // <-- Right here
            }, 500*i);
         })(a);
    }
}
```

- Updated to fullfill the 2nd req: showBranch() in 500ms steps..

Comment: Please don't use the term "closure" to describe this kind of solution. The callback passed to `setTimeout` is *already* a closure. The actual solution is to create a new scope by executing a function, not by creating yet another closure. Whether the executed function is a closure or not doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: +1 but define the function outside the for loop, because it creates one **each time** you iterate

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/HXc4d/

```
function showBranch_init() {
    var id_arr = ["jdc_b1","jdc_b2","jdc_b3","jdc_b4"];
    for(a=0;a<id_arr.length;a++){
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function(idvalue) {
            showBranch(idvalue);
        }(id_arr[a]), 500);
    }
}
```

EDIT: The problem with your solution is the fact that when the code executes (timeout) id_arr no longer exists in the executing scope, thus leading to `undefined` result. When sending the variable as an argument it "stays" with the funciton itself, regardless of the executing scope.

Comment: Could you please **explain** your solution, instead of just posting code? What's wrong with the OP's code?

Answer (score -1):

```
function showBranch_init() {
var id_arr = ["jdc_b1","jdc_b2","jdc_b3","jdc_b4"];

    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function() {
      for(a=0;a<id_arr.length;a++){
        showBranch(id_arr[a]); // <-- Right here
      }
    }, 500);
}
```

can you do that?? O_O